# How do I get a windows xp laptop to be able to use the internet via droid X?

Tags: tethering, windows

My friend has a droid x and her laptop has windows xp. She tried several ways to try to get the droid to work so it can be able to allow her computer to get on the internet via droid. I have come to find that there wasn't any drivers on her computer for the droid, even when installing drivers from

http://www.verizon-phones.org/verizon-motorola-droid-x-usb-drivers-pc-charging-drivers-download.html

her computer still does not recognize it. What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: How are you tethering?  Officially via Verizon or via rooted app such as Wifi Tether?

Comment: You can also alternatively consider using PDAnet http://www.junefabrics.com/android/

Answer (score 1):

There are two options, but they both require connecting to the Android device via WiFi:

- Root the phone and use Wireless Tether - (unofficial method) **Warning: this may void your warranty, so don't blame anyone if it causes you an issue, least of all me!  Proceed at your own risk.**  Once the phone is rooted (you can search via Google for rooting your device and it *usually* not the most complicated thing to do), you can install Wireless Tether from the Android Market.  This will basically turn your Android phone into a mobile router that you can connect to with your PC.

or

- Pay for the 3G Mobile Hotspot option from Verizon - (official version) This is the carrier provided method for tethering your device (getting a computer to access the internet using a wireless device).  I believe that it is currently $20 per month and there is a limit to the amount of data that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the drivers straight from the source (Motorola) [here](http://www.motorola.com/consumers/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=bda09ec8009a0210VgnVCM1000008806b00aRCRD).

Make sure any drivers you already installed are uninstalled first, then install from Motorola.